# comparison: neo4j vs titan

Tags: java, neo4j, titan

I'm working on a project in which I used Neo4j for building Social-network graph. But I found that Neo4j takes a lot of memory space. For about 35k nodes and 30k edges, it took more than 5GB of disk-space. I'm worried, if I want to create a graph with hundreds of millions of users and same range of edges, it'll take a lot of space which I'll not be able to manage for.

So while looking for alternative graphDB I found "titan". Before going ahead and try it, I would like to know, if anybody can give me comparison between these two databases (neo4j and titan) with respect to (1) memory usage, (2) speed of query response on vertices and edges properties, (3) availability, security and any other additional important parameter..

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data did you store in your nodes and relationships? The space everything takes is explained here http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache

Comment: Normally, holding 100s of millions primitives in memory should work on decent hardware.

Comment: I have around 10-15 primitive and 5-10 Lists of custom-class as properties for each Node and Relationship.. Properties are stored as JSON strings.

Counting together, on average for each Node and Relationship there would be properties equivalent to around 1000 primitives.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the graph size by modifying the *"neostore."* properties as explained on the [kernel configuration page](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/kernel-configuration.html). I'd suggest you play around and see what happens.